# Transparent to Solid effect for Android Lollipop Toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, toolbar, fading

In Android Lollipop 5.0, I am trying to make the toolbar for a fragment have an effect where it goes from a `Transparent` to a `Solid` color when the `listview` under it scrolls up. I have see a lot of implementations of this before lollipop. Has someone done this for a fragment in lollipop?

Answer (score 0):

You can do. Now it even easier - just change alpha channel depends on position of ListView. Kickoff example:

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int i1, int i2) {
                //invert your color changing policy
                toolbar.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255 - firstVisibleItem, 30, 30, 30));
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I change alpha as a function of the scroll position so that it turns to a solid color when scrolled down and transparent again when user scrolls up.

Comment: @user3773337 Solution is here (in my sample), just spend some efforts to make it fit all your needs.